# Decoding XML entities in Postgresql

Tags: xml, postgresql

I'm having trouble with xpath() in PostgreSQL. For example...

```sql
WITH x(col) AS (
    SELECT '<?xml version="1.0" ?><response><status>ERROR &amp; DATA</status></response>'::xml)
SELECT xpath('//status/text()', col) AS status
FROM   x
```

I would like this to return `ERROR & DATA` but instead it returns `ERROR &amp; DATA`, leaving the XML entity encoded. How can I decode this in Postgres?

Comment: I have a bad feeling about this. [BUG #7844: xpath missing entity decoding - bug or feature](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAAY5AM3CjMcq2qMUX6gBPPcT%2BH9xDCjJb0tAGbrW3ra9SytJfA%40mail.gmail.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`XMLTABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-xml.html#FUNCTIONS-XML-PROCESSING-XMLTABLE):

```
WITH x(col) AS (
SELECT '<?xml version="1.0" ?><response><status>ERROR &amp; DATA</status></response>'::xml
)
SELECT s.status
FROM x, XMLTABLE('//status' PASSING x.col COLUMNS status TEXT PATH '.') s;

--ERROR & DATA
```

**[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ce93fcd4e54b7a9e5a68deaf299764b2)**

Comment: Very nice, I'm glad I asked! This particular syntax only works on version 10 and above. Anything for 9.6 or is that getting too old?

Comment: @MartinBurch Yes, it was introduced in [PostgreSQL 10](https://www.depesz.com/2017/03/09/waiting-for-postgresql-10-support-xmltable-query-expression/)